# Oracle-Using optional prameters in function?

Tags: oracle, parameters

I want to add at most three optional parameters to my Oracle function named TEST.
Returned value should be 2.
How to modify my function to make these queries work in a simplest way?

```
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1') TEST0 FROM DUAL; -- Shows 2 correctly    
--How to make these queries also work?
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1','c1') TEST1 FROM DUAL;
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1','c1','d1') TEST2 FROM DUAL;
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1','c1','d1','e1') TEST3 FROM DUAL;
```

Table and Function are as below.

Table as below

```
CREATE TABLE T5 (
COL1 VARCHAR2(10),
COL2 VARCHAR2(10),
COL3 VARCHAR2(10),
COL4 VARCHAR2(10),
COL5 VARCHAR2(10),
VAL VARCHAR2(10)
);
INSERT INTO T5  VALUES ('eq1','md1','c1','d1','e1','2');
INSERT INTO T5  VALUES ('eq2','md2','c2','d2','e2','5');
INSERT INTO T5  VALUES ('eq3','md3','c3','d3','e3','3');
```

My funtion is,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST
(p1 IN VARCHAR2,
 p2 IN VARCHAR2
                  --How to add optional parameter p3?
                  --How to add optional parameter p4?
                  --How to add optional parameter p5?
)
RETURN NUMBER AS V_VALUE VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
SELECT(
    SELECT VAL  FROM T5
    WHERE COL1 = p1
    AND COL2 = p2
                  --How to add constraint COL3=p3?
                  --How to add constraint COL4=p4?
                  --How to add constraint COL5=p5?                      
    )
INTO V_VALUE
FROM DUAL;    
RETURN V_VALUE;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the `default` value and that's it.

Your function code should look like as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TEST (
    P1   IN   VARCHAR2,
    P2   IN   VARCHAR2,
    P3   IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    P4   IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    P5   IN   VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN NUMBER AS
    V_VALUE   VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT
        (
            SELECT
                VAL
            FROM
                T5
            WHERE
                COL1 = P1
                AND COL2 = P2
                AND COL3 = COALESCE(P3, COL3)
                AND COL4 = COALESCE(P4, COL4)
                AND COL5 = COALESCE(P5, COL5)
        )
    INTO V_VALUE
    FROM
        DUAL;

    RETURN V_VALUE;
END TEST;
/
```

Now, all the queries will run:

```
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1') TEST0 FROM DUAL;
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1','c1') TEST1 FROM DUAL;
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1','c1','d1') TEST2 FROM DUAL;
SELECT TEST('eq1','md1','c1','d1','e1') TEST3 FROM DUAL;
```

But, Please make sure that `order` of the passed parameter in the `function` is not broken.
You can not pass the `P5` without passing `P4` parameter value except the parameter names are used while calling the function.

Cheers!!